I got an error when providing the above='md' prop to <Show>
import { Grid, GridItem, Show } from "@chakra-ui/react"

function App() {
  return <Grid templateAreas={
    {
      base: `"nav" "main"`,
      md: `"nav nav" "aside main"`
    }
  }>
    <GridItem area='nav' bg='coral'>
      Nav
    </GridItem>

    <Show above='md'> // Error: #1
      <GridItem area='aside ' bg='red'>
        Aside
      </GridItem>
    </Show>
    
    <GridItem area='main' bg='pink'>
      Main
    </GridItem>
  </Grid>
}

export default App


#1:  Type '{ children: Element; above: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ShowProps'.
Property 'above' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ShowProps'.
I tried to install all the packages from Chakra UI, but it still doesn't work.
npm install @chakra-ui/react@latest
npm install @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react @emotion/styled framer-motion 
The version of chakra.ui is  :
"@chakra-ui/react": "^3.1.2"
Maybe I forgot to install something

Fix the GridItem area prop typo: "asbide" to "aside"
As you have mentioned above in templateAreas
templateAreas={
{
base: "nav" "main",
md: "nav nav" "aside main"
}
}


<Show above="md">
        <GridItem area="aside" bg="red">
          Aside
        </GridItem>
      </Show>




i fixed that but there is same error as before :
<Show above="md">
    <GridItem area="aside" bg="red">
      Aside
    </GridItem>
  </Show>


But it works with  and , but when I type above or below, it doesn't even show up in the list of properties, except for {when, fallback}, which are in the list. Maybe it's because of new version of chakra, how do you think?

I tested your code and it works fine for me, only error was that typo.
Current stable version of chakra UI is:
@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.2,
Try on this version, it will work.
